# Delphi-OpenCV gaussian blur?

Tags: delphi, opencv, delphi-2010

I'm trying out Delphi-OpenCV from here https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV and trying to port this code:

```
void unsharpMask(cv::Mat& im) 
{
    cv::Mat tmp;
    cv::GaussianBlur(im, tmp, cv::Size(5,5), 5);
    cv::addWeighted(im, 1.5, tmp, -0.5, 0, im);
}
```

However, I cant see an implementation of the gaussianBlur function.

Am I missing something or has anyone got a suggestion for a work around?

Thanks

@Laex - Great bit of work, thanks for making it available.

Comment: in file https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV/blob/master/source/component/ocv.comp.ImageOperation.pas look for TocvSmoothOperation class

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pIplImage as input, take a look at cvSmooth() and cvAddWeighted() procedures

```
cvSmooth(const src: pIplImage;dst: pIplImage;smoothtype: Integer = CV_GAUSSIAN;size1: Integer = 3;size2: Integer = 0;sigma1: double = 0;sigma2: double = 0);
cvAddWeighted(const src1: pIplImage; alpha: double; const src2: pIplImage; beta: double; gamma: double; dst: pIplImage);
```